# compile error using openssl

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, openssl

I try to use openSSL on a app but I get a parse issue on the following line (in the rsa.h header file)

```
int (*rsa_mod_exp)(BIGNUM *r0,const BIGNUM *I,RSA *rsa,BN_CTX *ctx);
```

error is : parse error expected ')'

Using XCode 5 on OSX 10.9 and  openssl-1.0.1e

What can be the issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide the complete command and the complete error output.

Comment: no I still have this issue in on of my projects.

Comment: @AP. Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I just encountered it today.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone who sees this in the future, it's an amazingly simple solution: on the line quoted in the question, just change `BIGNUM *I` to `BIGNUM *i`. (That is, change the capital "I" to lowercase "i".)

Recompile, and everything should work! I have no idea why that works, but I trusted the interwebs and once again my faith was rewarded.

Comment: I can not do changes as mentioned here as I am using framework. Is here a way to go around?

Comment: @Ramis same here. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @SanyasiraoMopada I am using [OpneSSL builder](https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone). For me it build without problem.

Comment: I have started to maintain my own pod for [openssl](https://cocoapods.org/pods/openssl-ios-bitcode-ii), and have added steps in the pod processing to correct the rsa.h file per the suggestion above.

Answer (score 1):

It could be all sorts of things, either in the header or in the file before the point the header is included. If by looking at the region of source around the point it is not obvious you can try preprocessing the file.

In Xcode select Product -> Perform Action -> Preprocess "file" and you'll get an editor window containing the source the compiler actually sees after file inclusion and macro expansion. In that locate the point of the error, look around, and work backwards if needed, untill you spot the problem.